# JavaScript URL wildcard to mean any number or letter

Tags: javascript, regex, url, google-chrome-extension

I have two urls

```
https://www.etsy.com/cartsdgsr <random characters after cart>
```

and

```
https://www.etsy.com/cart/<random numbers>/review
```

at the beginning of the `js` page I run

```
if (document.URL.match("https://www.etsy.com/cart/*/review")) {
    //run this code here
 } else if (document.URL.match("https://www.etsy.com/cart*")) {
  //run code here
   }
```

but the `*` is not working how would I properly write this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you need:

```
if (document.URL.match(/^https:\/\/www\.etsy\.com\/cart\/\d+\/review/)) {
    //run this code here
} else if (document.URL.match(/^https:\/\/www\.etsy\.com\/cart\w+/)) {
    //run code here
}
```

As philnash mentioned, you need to pass a `RegExp` but not a string into the `String#match` function.

- `^` matches the start of the string
- `https:\/\/www\.etsy\.com\/cart\/` matches exactly `https://www.etsy.com/cart/`
- `\d+` means it matches at least one digit(e.g. `123`)
- `\/review` matches exact `/review`
- `\w+` matches at least one [*word character*](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_wordchar.asp) (e.g `l33t`)

Answer (score 1):

[`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) can match against a string, but if you want to match against a pattern then you will want to reach for a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

In this case, you are looking for one or more random characters in a certain spot. So your regular expressions could look like:

```
/^https:\/\/www\.etsy\.com\/cart\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/review$/
```

Or if you really mean that there are random numbers, you can use `\d` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, like

```
/^https:\/\/www\.etsy\.com\/cart\/\d+\/review$/
```

And

```
/^https:\/\/www\.etsy\.com\/cart[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

And fit into your example code:

```js
if (document.URL.match(/^https:\/\/www\.etsy\.com\/cart\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/review$/)) {
    //run this code here
 } else if (document.URL.match(/^https:\/\/www\.etsy\.com\/cart[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/)) {
  //run code here
   }
```

Comment: I suggest to use `\d+` in the first case since OP needs `<random numbers>`, Also you forgot to escape `/` and `.` :p